# Jet of water hitting a wall

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In my lecture course the following slide was given:

[image]

Is the justification for the pressure being P0 at a large radius Pascal's principle? Is there anything else that can be said about the fluid flow at closer distances or is this situation too complicated to analyse?

Answer (score 1):

Far from the impact on the wall the ambiant pressure is that of the atmosphere $P_0$. Since the pressure field is continuous, pressure at the edge of water must also be $P_0$. I don't think there's anything more to it.